# Determining PDF of a function of two dependent variables- where am I going wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So the problem says that the joint PDF of X and Y is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=y$$
$$ y \in[0,1], x \in [-1,1]$$
and I have to determine the PDF for $$f_Z(z)$$
$$Z=X+Y$$

Going by the standard procedure, I introduce a new variable $W=X$ and determine the Jacobian $J=-1$

Then, I say $$f_{Z,W}(z,w)={f_{X,Y}(W,Z-W)}\div{-1}=W-Z$$
Now, since $W=X, W \in [-1,1]$, so I should be able to integrate $\int_{-1}^1(W-Z)\it{dw}=f_Z$.

However, doing so gets a nonsense result of $-2Z$. I tried with $W=Y$, but then the integral is $1/2$ which is also nonsense,
because $Z\in{[-1,2]}$

Please, I really need help with this! Thanks

Comment: Be more careful with your notation. $f_{W,Z}(w,z)$ is a function of real variables $w$ and $z$ and so cannot _equal_ $W-Z$ which is a random variable. Also, pdfs need to be be specified in more detail than just the $w-z$ that you have managed to come up with, you need limitations on the values of $w$ and $z$, and a single expression might not suffice to specify the joint pdf for all $w$ and $z$. For example, your purported pdf $w-z$ has value $-\frac 12$ at $w=1,z=1\frac 12$ which clearly makes no sense and yet $W=X=1$ and $Z=X+Y=1+\frac 12=1\frac 12$ are valld values for $W$ and $Z$.

Comment: You're right, I should've used small letters, and I noticed that my Jacobian is actually equal to 1 so that means that the PDF should've been $z-w$, however  that still gives the result of 2z for $f_z(z)$ once integrated. Thank you for your answer, but do you maybe have a solution which I could follow, please?
Thanks