# can you give an example of two dependent random variables which their sum is uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, density-function

I need to find an example of two dependent random variables X and Y such that X+Y~U(0,2)
so I thought this way: I need to find a P(X+Y<=z) :

[P(X+Y<=z)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSIsG.png)
which would lead to this
[density function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APIoS.png) which will mean that X+Y~U(0,2)

however I couldn't find an example

Comment: Can you think of any simple examples that might be helpful here? For example, if $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0, 1)$, what are the resulting distributions if you apply simple transformations like $X + 1$, $2X$, etc.? Can any of these help you to find a suitable $Y$?

Comment: yes that can hep, thank you

Comment: Very similar to [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4339348/15941).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of 2 random variables s.t. $(X+Y)$ ~ $U(0,2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339450/example-of-2-random-variables-s-t-xy-u0-2)